# Joining python tables

Tags: python, pandas

I need to join two tables together:

E.g:

Table 1

```
index'      (GBP, USD)  (USD, RUB)   etc...
2019-07-01      1.1         62          ...
2019-07-02      1.2         63          ...
2019-07-03      1.3         64          ...
```

Table 2

```
date          pair  
2019-07-01  GBP, USD    
2019-07-01  USD, RUB    
2019-07-02  GBP, USD    
2019-07-02  USD, RUB
```

The aim is to add some sort of join which create a new column in table 2 showing the rate in table 1.

Final

```
date          pair     Rate
2019-07-01  GBP, USD    1.1
2019-07-01  USD, RUB    62 
2019-07-02  GBP, USD    1.2
2019-07-02  USD, RUB    63
```

I tried a few variations of pd.merge but could get what I was looking for. Maybe need to do something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Cleanup

This requires some clean up first.  `tbl1` needs to be in long format and we need to ensure that those columns are tuples rather than strings that look like tuples.

```
fx = tbl1.stack().rename_axis(['date', 'pair']).reset_index(name='FX')
fx['pair'] = fx['pair'].str[1:-1].str.split(', ').map(tuple)

fx

        date        pair    FX
0 2019-07-01  (GBP, USD)   1.1
1 2019-07-01  (USD, RUB)  62.0
2 2019-07-02  (GBP, USD)   1.2
3 2019-07-02  (USD, RUB)  63.0
4 2019-07-03  (GBP, USD)   1.3
5 2019-07-03  (USD, RUB)  64.0
```

---

Or leave it alone and fix columns

```
tbl1.columns = tbl1.columns.str[1:-1].str.split(', ').map(tuple)

tbl1

            GBP USD
            USD RUB
index              
2019-07-01  1.1  62
2019-07-02  1.2  63
2019-07-03  1.3  64
```

---

`tbl2` need to ensure that `pair` column are tuples rather than strings that look like tuples.

```
tbl2 = tbl2.assign(pair=tbl2.pair.str.split(', ').map(tuple))

tbl2

                  pair
date                  
2019-07-01  (GBP, USD)
2019-07-01  (USD, RUB)
2019-07-02  (GBP, USD)
2019-07-02  (USD, RUB)
```

---

#### `lookup`

Using the fixed up `tbl1`

```
tbl2.assign(FX=tbl1.lookup(tbl2.index, tbl2.pair))

                  pair    FX
date                        
2019-07-01  (GBP, USD)   1.1
2019-07-01  (USD, RUB)  62.0
2019-07-02  (GBP, USD)   1.2
2019-07-02  (USD, RUB)  63.0
```

---

#### `pd.merge_asof`

Using the long format `fx`

```
 pd.merge_asof(tbl2, fx, on='date', by='pair')

         pair       date    FX
0  (GBP, USD) 2019-07-01   1.1
1  (USD, RUB) 2019-07-01  62.0
2  (GBP, USD) 2019-07-02   1.2
3  (USD, RUB) 2019-07-02  63.0
```

Comment: Big help! On part one though, when I look to getfx columns as tuples I get a error 'float' object is not iterable. I presume it doesn't like the numbers as float?